# Unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time - ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, foreach, swiftui

I have a JSON file structered like this:

```
// MARK: - UcmData
struct UcmData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let building: [Building]
}

// MARK: - Building
struct Building: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title, subtitle, info, image: String
    let floor: [Floor]
}

// MARK: - Floor
struct Floor: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id, number: Int
    let title, subtitle, image: String
    let cabinet: [Cabinet]?
}

// MARK: - Cabinet
struct Cabinet: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let number: String
    let person: [Person]
}

// MARK: - Person
struct Person: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

And I need to list all persons for each cabinet on a specific floor in a specific building - i'm trying to do this here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FloorDetailedView: View {
    let ucmData = Bundle.main.decode(UcmData.self, from: "ucm_data.json")
    let buildingId: Int?
    let floorId: Int?
    let floorTitle: String?
    let buildingTitle: String?

    init(buildingId: Int? = nil, floorId: Int? = nil, floorTitle: String? = "nil", buildingTitle: String? = "nil") {
        self.buildingId = buildingId
        self.floorId = floorId
        self.floorTitle = floorTitle
        self.buildingTitle = buildingTitle

    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(ucmData.building) { building in
                    if (building.id == self.buildingId) {
                        ForEach(building.floor) { floor in
                            if (floor.id == self.floorId) {
                                ForEach(floor.cabinet) { cabinet in
                                    Image(systemName: "house")
                                        .cornerRadius(40)
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text(cabinet.name)
                                        ForEach(cabinet.person) { person in
                                            Text(person.name)
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                                .color(.gray)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.buildingTitle! + " - " + self.floorTitle!), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

However, I get this error `Unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time` when I add 3rd `ForEach` to the view code. I get `buildingId` and `floorId` from the previous view. What is a more effective way, so I can filter the Cabinets and Persons and fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: The more instructions you added the more time it consumes... just break that VStack monster on several subviews.

Comment: But how is it possible when I still need to filter trough building.id and floor.id to find deeper objects in the hierarchy e.g. cabinet and person?

Comment: As an aside, I also had a triple ForEach in a View and although it compiled OK, the View didn't update properly under various reproducible situations. Separating out the last ForEach into another View solved the problem completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

SwiftUI compiler is telling us to break the expression into sub-expressions.
In other words, we need to break this view up into smaller sub views.

Such an error pops up when `SwiftUI`'s compiler identifies code that could lead to performance issues.
In your case you have a loop in a loop in a loop and that could be... bad!

That being said, the SwiftUI compiler is still being optimized to handle cases such as yours.

---

Now looking at your implementation, technically it should work but it has to be optimized.
Assuming the building/floor/cabinet ids are unique, your `ForEach` and `if` id checks for building and floor would execute only once.
Furthermore, it seems you want to show only the cabinets so why not go directly for that?

#### Solution:

```
struct FloorDetailedView: View {
  let ucmData: UcmData
  let buildingId: Int?
  let floorId: Int?
  
  var cabinets: [Cabinet]? { //1
    return ucmData
      .building
      .first { $0.id == self.buildingId }?
      .floor
      .first { $0.id == self.floorId }?
      .cabinet
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    Group {
      if cabinets != nil { //2
        CabinetView(cabinets: cabinets!) //3
      } else {
        Text("No Cabinets")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
struct CabinetView: View {
  let cabinets: [Cabinet]
  
  var body: some View {
    List(cabinets) { (cabinet) in
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Image(systemName: "house")

        Text(cabinet.number)

        ForEach(cabinet.person) { (person) in
          Text(person.name)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. We reduced the complexity by having a computed property `cabinets` that goes through `ucmData` by utilizing `buildingId` and `floorId`
2. We check if cabinets are available to show. If no cabinets available, we simply show a message
3. `CabinetView` is separated out

Comment: This is great solution, I did not know I can skip checking for building and floor like this, thank you!

Comment: @redearz Glad to help :) well... top-down approaches generally suffers from clarity since we have to consider multiple things. bottom-up approach allows you to concentrate on the task at hand. assume you have what you need, work on it and then figure out how to provide this object.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this creating 2 separate views:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CabinetView: View {
    let floor: Floor?
    let floorId: Int?

    init(floor: Floor? = nil, floorId: Int? = nil) {
        self.floor = floor
        self.floorId = floorId
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(floor!.cabinet!) { cabinet in
            Group {
                HStack {
                     Image("avatar")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .border(Color.gray.opacity(0.5), width: 0.5)
                        .cornerRadius(40/2)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                        Text(cabinet.number)
                        ForEach(cabinet.person) { person in
                            Text(person.name)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this one:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FloorDetailedView: View {
    let ucmData = Bundle.main.decode(UcmData.self, from: "ucm_data.json")
    let buildingId: Int?
    let floorId: Int?
    let floorTitle: String?
    let buildingTitle: String?

    init(buildingId: Int? = nil, floorId: Int? = nil, floorTitle: String? = "nil", buildingTitle: String? = "nil") {
        self.buildingId = buildingId
        self.floorId = floorId
        self.floorTitle = floorTitle
        self.buildingTitle = buildingTitle

    }

    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(ucmData.building) { building in
                    if (building.id == self.buildingId) {
                        ForEach(building.floor) { floor in
                            if (floor.id == self.floorId) {
                                CabinetView(floor: floor, floorId: self.floorId)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.buildingTitle! + " - " + self.floorTitle!), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```